# Why does form submit passing name of button? Codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I want to pass a date using an input form. When I click Confirm there is no data sending. Code just sends a name of submit button.

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'peugot',
    'id'   => 'peugot',
    'value' => 'Dni',
    'size'  => '15',
    'min'  => '2017-01-01',
    'max' => '2017-12-31',
    'style'=> 'width:15%',
    'type'=> 'date'
    );
echo form_input($data);
echo form_submit('peugot', 'Confirm');   // I think it should submit $data but It send word "Confirm"
```

Another file

```
<?php
$peugot = $this->input->post('peugot');
echo $peugot;  // Echo "Confirm" ?!
```

Comment: I don't know Codeigniter, but my assumtion is that `echo form_submit('peugot', 'Confirm');` creates a form element `<input name="peugot" type="submit" value="Confirm" />`. And since it is **after** your `$data = array( 'name' => 'peugot', ...` it overwrites your form element. Try changing the name of one or the other, ie `echo form_submit('peugot1', 'Confirm');`

Comment: That's correct. Thank you so much.

Comment: Just check example in docs. It is very clear from there that you are passing `Confirm` as value of field. Second place in helper's function is reserved for field value. [Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#form_submit).